# MySQL replication - Should I handle load balancing from my client code (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, replication, load-balancing

In a MySQL master-slave replication enviroment if I have 4 slave servers how can I execute load balanced select queries?

Should I write a PHP class to dealing with the 4 slaves or it is possible to address queries to MySQL's own load balancer solution? Is there any MySQL load balancing solution?

Can I use some other tool to distribute my queries? What is the typical set up in situations like this?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common practice would be to set up something like ldirectord in front of your mysql cluster to provide a virtual ip as a load balanced address for the cluster, this could then distribute your queries to the various mysql servers.

This would require ipvs routing which may/may not be overkill for your specific situation, it may be that php control of the load balancing would be appropriate for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

There are really two questions to be answered:

1. Should this query go to a slave, or the master db?

   - This logic should probably be in PHP.  There are often cases where you must have the absolute freshest data, which can't be had from a slave.  For example, if a user alters a page, you need to build the updated page from the master db -- the user's changes may have not made it to the slave dbs yet.  This is very application-specific, so 3rd party tools may not be able to do this for you.
2. Which slave should this query go to?

   - This, you probably don't need to write yourself -- it's not really important to your application which specific slave handles a request.  Existing tools should handle this well.